# access member of a for loop in tqdm desc keyword argument

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

Is it possible to access the current item in a for loop in the prefix of a progressbar (the `desc` keyword argument).  That is, to get something like this to work:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for x in tqdm(['a' ,'b', 'c'], desc='item {}'.format(x)):
    pass
```

That code produces a `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` at the line of the `for` loop.  Could it be made instead to create a progressbar where the prefix updates with `x` in the for loop.

```
item a: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
item b: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 2/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
item c: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
pbar = tqdm(["a", "b", "c"])
for x in pbar:
    pbar.set_description('item {}'.format(x))
```